# How to handle delete operation in spring if there are no record in database table?

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am using JdbcDaoSupport in DAO class for database coding in my project and there is a scenario for "deleting a member" from a table. I am using `getJdbcTemplate.update("delete MEMBERINFO where memid= "+id);` method. But if there is no data in the table, it doesn't raise any exception. The criteria is such that if there are no records in the table and yet user is trying to delete a record, then user will receive an error message saying "No data found". But for that, i need to raise an exception.

I am using oracle 11g XE.

Also same problem for `getJdbcTemplate.query("select * from MEMBERINFO");`
If there is no data it does not raise any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `JdbcTemplate's` update method returns int - number of rows was affected. All you need is to check amount of rows returned. If it's 0 the you can show an error message.

As for query it's fine that list is empty. If you need just one object use
`queryForObject()` method. It throws exception if no result is found.

BTW: The `getJdbcTemplate.update("delete MEMBERINFO where memid= "+id);` contains SQL injection. Use parameters instead.

Comment: yes i got it.
but how will i execute getJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from MEMBERINFO")
it is raising exception
i mean select * from MEMBERINFO : if i want to get no of records returned whats the procedure?

Comment: If you need rows call query, if you need just one value call queryForObject. BTW you can call queryForObject("select count(*) from MEMBERINFO") if you need just count of rows

Comment: queryForObject("select count(*) from MEMBERINFO")
initially it was showing error but i modified it as

queryForObject("select count(*) from MEMBERINFO", Integer.class)
now working fine